# False convergence in competing risks regression when using the cmprsk package

Tags: r

I was using the crr() function in the cmprsk package to perform the competing risks regression. However, it fails with the warning "crr converged: FALSE". I have performed the competing risk regression for many times and this is the first time I have met the question.

```
    x_total2 <- cbind(factor2ind(m1_sub3), factor2ind(age1, "1"), factor2ind(sex2, "1"), factor2ind(race2, "1"), 
              factor2ind(marital2, "1"), factor2ind(grade2, "1"), factor2ind(t_stage2, "1"), 
              factor2ind(n_stage2, "1"), factor2ind(ssct2, "0"))

    mod_nrt1 <- crr(surv_mo, sum_cod3, x_total2[,c(1:24)])

    summary.crr(mod_nrt1, digits = max(options()$digits - 4, 3))
```

Here is the warning.

```
    Competing Risks Regression

    Call:
    crr(ftime = surv_mo, fstatus = sum_cod3, cov1 = x_total2[, c(1:24)])

    crr converged: FALSE
```

After this warning, I used

```
    mod_nrt1[["converged"]] <- TRUE
```

Through this function, I could get the results as follows.

```
               exp(coef) exp(-coef)     2.5%    97.5%
    sex2:2      4.36e+00   2.30e-01 1.28e+00 1.48e+01
    race2:2     1.30e+00   7.67e-01 8.71e-01 1.95e+00
    race2:3     1.17e+00   8.58e-01 6.58e-01 2.07e+00
    race2:4     2.42e+00   4.13e-01 1.18e+00 4.98e+00
    race2:5     3.57e-05   2.80e+04 4.15e-06 3.07e-04
    t_stage2:2  2.60e-01   3.85e+00 1.10e-01 6.12e-01
    t_stage2:3  2.75e-01   3.64e+00 1.16e-01 6.51e-01
    t_stage2:4  4.08e-01   2.45e+00 1.53e-01 1.09e+00
    t_stage2:5  2.74e-01   3.65e+00 1.05e-01 7.14e-01
    t_stage2:6  8.58e-01   1.17e+00 2.80e-01 2.63e+00
    n_stage2:2  1.01e+00   9.91e-01 4.70e-01 2.16e+00
    n_stage2:3  6.97e-01   1.44e+00 2.74e-01 1.77e+00
    n_stage2:4  1.26e+00   7.95e-01 5.30e-01 2.98e+00
    n_stage2:5  3.22e+00   3.10e-01 1.01e+00 1.02e+01
    ssct2:0     3.74e+00   2.68e-01 1.75e+00 7.96e+00
    ssct2:1     2.92e+00   3.42e-01 1.36e+00 6.27e+00
    ssct2:3     9.93e-01   1.01e+00 6.49e-01 1.52e+00
```

I know it's wrong. What's the perfect solution? Is there anything wrong with the original data?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing maxiter (default is 10)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please share a reproducible piece of your data so that others can use it and help you more efficiently.